# split a string only if it contains multiple year in it and make a custom string

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, split

I have a String in below format:

```
[string1][string2][string3][string4][string5][string6]
```

in which first string which is `string1` will always be `Year` and it will be in this format `YYYY` so sample example is:

```
[2010][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
```

Now in some cases, `string1` is coming in this format `2010^K2011^K2012^K2013^K2014^K2015^K2016^K2017` in which each year is separated by `^K` delimiter. Sample example:

```
[2010^K2011^K2012^K2013^K2014^K2015^K2016^K2017][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
```

Now whenever I see strings in above format, I have to parse year string and split on the delimiter and extract each individual year and then make list of strings in this below format:

```
[2010][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
[2011][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
[2012][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
[2013][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
[2014][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
[2015][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
[2016][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
[2017][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
```

So I can think of below cases:

- If year string has only one year then I will use that as it is without any splitting.
- If year string has multiple years in it separated by some delimiter then I will split that year and  make list of strings accordingly as shown above.
- If that year string doesn't have year in it for whatever reason then I will use the string whatever it is there as it is without any splitting or anything.

Is this possible to do? I know how to split a string on a special character `^` but confusion is how to extract `string1` and check whether it has multiple years in it (if yes then split it) or it has only one year in it or it has something else.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // String myString =
    // "[2010^K2011^K2012^K2013^K2014^K2015^K2016^K2017][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]";
    String myString = "[2010][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]";

  }
```

Comment: Is ^K two characters, or single control character, ASCII 11?

Comment: Well first of all split the main info (strings 1-6) and store.  then split and loop on string1

Comment: First show your code what you have done so far. I think you are wanting the direct solution of the problem. Just try some your logic.

Comment: @hyde I believe it's a single control character ASCII 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with this method:

```
public static String[] splitYears(String str) {
    // get the year part of the string using a regex
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^\\[([\\d^K]+)\\]").matcher(str);
    if(m.find()) {
        String yearPart = m.group(1);
        // separate the other parts. The + 2 here is to account for the two square brackets in the yearPart
        String otherParts = str.substring(yearPart.length() + 2);
        // split by ^K
        String[] years = yearPart.split("\\^K");
        // Construct a new string for each year
        String[] newYears = new String[years.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
            newYears[i] = String.format("[%s]%s", years[i], otherParts);
        }
        return newYears;
    } else {
        return new String[] {str};
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitYears("[2010^K2011^K2012^K2013^K2014^K2015^K2016^K2017][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]")));
```

Comment: I was suspecting that it can be done with regex. I am still on Java 7 so can you provide an example with Java 7?

Comment: @user1950349 Updated.

Comment: yeah I just tried. What I am noticing is it is adding an extra square bracket to each string? In my case, I don't need that. Is there any way to get rid of that? If you look at my example in the question, I don't have an extra square bracket for each of the string.

Comment: @user1950349 It's the result of `Arrays.toString`. Try using a for loop to print each string on a separate line.

Answer (score 1):

As now I see there is an accepted answer for your question, I want to show you my attempts to solve your problem - you might want to give it a try or maybe find something interesting here anyway (I added some explanations in the comments to the code)

### Solution with the use of regex:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String s1 = "[2010][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]";
       String s2 = "[2010^K2011^K2012^K2013^K2014][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]";

       String[] oneYearString = transformString(s1);
       String[] moreYearsString = transformString(s2);

       for(String s : oneYearString) {
                      System.out.println(s);
       }
       System.out.println();

       for(String s : moreYearsString) {
          System.out.println(s);
       }
    }

    public static String[] transformString(String source) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\[([^]]+)(.*)"); // contents of first square bracket are in first matching group
                                                                     // in first parenthesis (), the following part is in second matching group parenthesis 
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(source); // matcher that compares source String with given pattern
        String[] result;
        while(m.find()) {
            if(m.group(1).length() == 4) { //if there are 4 characters in first square bracket... 
                result = new String[] {source};
                return result; // return String[] containing only one element
            } else { // if there are more than 4 characters... 
                String[] splittedYears = m.group(1).split("\\^K"); // split content of first bracket on given delimiter
                result = new String[splittedYears.length]; // here you're gonna store result Strings
                for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    String entry = "[" + splittedYears[i] + m.group(2); // creating properly formatted string for each year
                    result[i] = entry; // adding properly prepared String to array
                }
                return result; // return String[] with results
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Output that you get when executing it:

```
[2010][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]

[2010][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
[2011][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
[2012][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
[2013][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
[2014][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]
```

### Solution without regex:

(Posting only changed method)

```
public static String[] transformString(String source) {
    String firstBracket = source.substring(source.indexOf('[') + 1, source.indexOf(']'));
    String[] result;
    if(firstBracket.length() == 4) {
        result = new String[] {source};
        return result;
    } else {
        System.out.println(firstBracket);
        String[] splittedYears = firstBracket.split("\\^K");
        result = new String[splittedYears.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            String entry = "[" + splittedYears[i] + source.substring(source.indexOf(']'));
            result[i] = entry;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even this will work

```
String str = "([0-9]{4})(.*?(?=\\d))?(?:.*?)(\\[.*)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(str);
    String input = "[2010^K2011^K2012^K2013^K2014^K2015^K2016^K2017][Toyota][ALL][Hatchback][998ccm 68HP 50KW]";
    Matcher matcher;
    do
    {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            System.out.println("[" + matcher.group(1) + "]" + matcher.group(3));
            input = input.replace(matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2), "");
        }
    } while (matcher.group(2) != null);
```

Answer (score -1):

java.lang.String has a few methods to make this easy.

You probably should split to seperate each string isolating "string1" as Scary Wombat suggested. something like:

```
String[] stringArray = myString.split("]\\[|\\[|]");
```

Note: that will create an empty string at [0].

To prevent this I would preemptively remove the first "[" with

```
myString.replaceFirst();
```

Now that you have an array of strings, the first element is your year.

```
for(String year : stringArray.split("\\^K")
{
    do things in here.
}
```